# for() loop displays $row_record[] once but $message $i times - PHP

Tags: php

```
$RecordCount=mysql_num_rows($pnname); 

for($el=1; $el<=$RecordCount;$el++) {
$message .= "test--test";

echo $el."--".$row_pnname01['pnom']."<BR>";
echo $message."<BR>";


}
```

Here the `$message` is displayed `$i` count times, ie., if `$i` =5 `$message` is displayed 5 times but `$row_pnname01['pnom']` is displayed only once each `$i` count.

Any idea on why it is happening.  Sure something that I must have overlooked.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: You are not resetting `$message` but keep appending to it.

Comment: AAH! got it.. could you put that as an answer. I knew there was something I over looked :)..Thanks

Comment: Well, JohnFx already posted the answer. :) Let him have it.

Comment: @irobot enter as answer for me to credit you.

Comment: Give it to JohnFx please, no need to post the same answer twice just for credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this

```
$message .= "test--test";
```

Do this

```
$message = "test--test";
```

Comment: I am using $message.=""; and another line $message.=""; So I guess $message=""; does the trick.

Comment: I don't see that in the code in your question. Remember that .= is appending the value to the current value. $message.="" won't clear out the $message variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$RecordCount=mysql_num_rows($pnname); 

for ($el=1; $el<=$RecordCount;$el++) {
  $message = "test--test";

  echo $el."--".$row_pnname01['pnom']."<BR>";
  echo $message."<BR>";
}
```

This should do the trick. The `$message .= "test--test";` keeps appending the string "test--test" to the variable `$message`. While using the `=` and not the `.=` will simply assign a new value to `$message`.